# Can I use a private on-prem database with cloudbees

Tags: cloudbees

I have a database behind a firewall - can I connect to it from cloudbees? What are the options?

Answer (score 2):

The best option is to use the "Weave" on-prem connector:

[Weave on prem connector](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/FoxWeave/On-Premise+Deployment+Guide)

This runs as a little app, that opens a (secure) outbound websocket, allowing you to get data from private databases from your cloud hosted app.

Other options involve:

- write an app that syncs data from your internal DB to a cloud DB
- open up the your database via a firewall rule/VPN to the cloud (this can be helped by having fixed IPs that your cloud servers use).

Comment: I like the way you answer your own question :)

Comment: I like that feature of Stackoverflow - tick the box "answer your own question" for a knowledge base style entry. I don't know how many times I have done it - and then found my own answer later on (who needs a memory!)